# Task.FromResult vs async without await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Are the two code snippets below equivalent?

*Using Task.FromResult*

```cs
public Task<string> Foo() {
    return Task.FromResult("foo");
}
```

*Using async without await*

```cs
public async Task<string> Foo() {
    return "foo";
}
```

If not equivalent, what is the difference?

Comment: equivalent yes, though using "async" without an "await" in the method will produce a warning.

Comment: second one will generate `IAsyncStateMachine` implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the end user the answer is **Yes**.

But the generated code from the **C# Compiler** will be very different.
The **async / await** is generating state machine.

You can check the generated code [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwKwG5nJQDMmM6AwugN7Lp2YlQAcmAbADwDKALgE4CWAOwDmAPnQAVAKYBnbgEEZAT0EBjABQBKarXp6oAdnQAiY/iR6AvsktA===) and more about the state machine [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) and [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-1-compilation) if you are interested.

Comment: Oh! That is a difference in generated code overhead. Thanks for the useful links. The purpose was to understand async/await better, and your answer surely helped!

Answer (score 1):

Like previous users mentioned, the result will be the same for the end user, but the compiler will use the state machine.

These code changes can be very easily be seen / analyzed using https://sharplab.io/

So using the following method:

```
public class SomeClass 
{

    public async Task<bool> DidObjectChange(string fontFamily, string glyph, int size, string color, CompareToThisClass compareTo)
    {
        if(fontFamily != compareTo.FontFamily)
            return true;

        if(glyph != compareTo.Glyph)
            return true;

        if (size != compareTo.Size)
            return true;

        if (color != compareTo.Color)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
    
   
}

public class CompareToThisClass
{
    public string FontFamily { get; set; }       
    public string Glyph { get; set; }     
    public int Size { get; set; }     
    public string Color { get; set; }     
}
```

returns the following compiled code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
[CompilerGenerated]
private struct <DidObjectChange>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public int <>1__state;

    public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool> <>t__builder;

    public string fontFamily;

    public CompareToThisClass compareTo;

    public string glyph;

    public int size;

    public string color;

    private void MoveNext()
    {
        bool result;
        try
        {
            result = fontFamily != compareTo.FontFamily || glyph != compareTo.Glyph || size != compareTo.Size || ((color != compareTo.Color) ? true : false);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            <>1__state = -2;
            <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
            return;
        }
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
        this.MoveNext();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        <>t__builder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in SetStateMachine
        this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }
}

[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<DidObjectChange>d__0))]
public Task<bool> DidObjectChange(string fontFamily, string glyph, int size, string color, CompareToThisClass compareTo)
{
    <DidObjectChange>d__0 stateMachine = default(<DidObjectChange>d__0);
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool>.Create();
    stateMachine.fontFamily = fontFamily;
    stateMachine.glyph = glyph;
    stateMachine.size = size;
    stateMachine.color = color;
    stateMachine.compareTo = compareTo;
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    stateMachine.<>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

while using it without async:

```
public class SomeClass 
{

    public Task<bool> DidObjectChange(string fontFamily, string glyph, int size, string color, CompareToThisClass compareTo)
    {
        if(fontFamily != compareTo.FontFamily)
            return Task.FromResult(true);

        if(glyph != compareTo.Glyph)
            return Task.FromResult(true);

        if (size != compareTo.Size)
            return Task.FromResult(true);

        if (color != compareTo.Color)
            return Task.FromResult(true);

        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
    
   
}

public class CompareToThisClass
{
    public string FontFamily { get; set; }       
    public string Glyph { get; set; }     
    public int Size { get; set; }     
    public string Color { get; set; }     
}
```

returns the following compiled code:

```
public Task<bool> DidObjectChange(string fontFamily, string glyph, int size, string color, CompareToThisClass compareTo)
{
    if (fontFamily != compareTo.FontFamily)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
    if (glyph != compareTo.Glyph)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
    if (size != compareTo.Size)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
    if (color != compareTo.Color)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
    return Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

In the end, when benchmarking both methods, the (performance) result is almost the same, the benchmark result setting `RunBenchmarkTaskAsync` as `baseline`:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Ratio | RatioSD | Rank | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RunBenchmarkTaskAsync | 43.08 ns | 1.732 ns | 4.998 ns | 41.49 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 1 | 0.0076 | 48 B |
| RunBenchmarkTaskWithoutAsync | 43.73 ns | 1.537 ns | 4.076 ns | 43.33 ns | 1.04 | 0.16 | 2 | 0.0076 | 48 B |

The results setting `RunBenchmarkTaskWithoutAsync` as `baseline`:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Ratio | RatioSD | Rank | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RunBenchmarkTaskWithoutAsync | 36.77 ns | 1.963 ns | 5.694 ns | 34.94 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 1 | 0.0076 | 48 B |
| RunBenchmarkTaskAsync | 49.45 ns | 2.646 ns | 7.761 ns | 47.96 ns | 1.38 | 0.33 | 2 | 0.0076 | 48 B |

Link to the benchmark project:
https://github.com/NicolasKlaas/BenchmarkTest.git

Comment: *"So TL;DR: a lot less overhead."* -- How are you measuring the overhead? In lines of code? Have you done any actual benchmarks?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias a very valid point. Edited the post with the benchmark, the result actually surprised me :)

Comment: Nicolas never underestimate a highly optimized state machine! :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias so it seems :-) however, after running a second benchmark using 
`BenchmarkDotNet`, and setting the `baseline` from `RunBenchmarkTaskAsync` to `RunBenchmarkTaskWithoutAsync` it yields some different results (making the TaskWithoutAsync run 10~ NS faster). Sadly my knowledge about `BenchmarkDotNet` and the `baseline` property is limited. *Edited the post (again) based on the new findings.

Comment: Nicolas I think that it is safe to say that any difference in performance between using or [eliding](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) async/await is so small, to a point that worrying about it is unproductive in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that async wraps exceptions in the return Task with stack trace determined by where you *await*.

You basicly have to decide between performance and safety.